# Counting points creating polygon with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, count, shape-area

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

In land consolidation projects, to determine success of the project, we use shape indices. For this purpose to calculate shape indices, I need to know how many points creates each polygon in attribute table.

Comment: Add geometry attributes will do a job.

Answer (score 4):

From [How To: Count the vertices for line or polygon features in ArcMap 10](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011230):

Procedure

1.Right-click the layer to be evaluated in the Table of Contents and click Open Attribute Table.

2.From the Table Options drop-down, click Add Field to add a new field to the table.

3.Name the field VxCount and select Long Integer for the field type. Click OK.

4.Right-click the heading of the new field and click Field Calculator.
Under Parser, select Python.
In the main expression box, set:

```
VxCount = !shape!.pointcount
```

If you dont want to count the polygon start and endpoint (which is at the same location) twice:

```
VxCount = !shape!.pointcount-1
```

Comment: @Fırat Arslan , nice, can you accept my answer with the checkbox?

Comment: +1, but three remarks: i) python is case sensitive, so you should use "pointCount" (capital C) ii) shape is the geometry field name, which could also be Shape or a completely different name (also case sensitive) iii) If the geometry is correct, there will be a start and an end point "closing" the polygon, at the same position. so for index computation, it is more relevant to use !Shape!.pointCount -1

Comment: @radouxju, I just copy-pasted it from ESRI :). I tried it now though both on a fc in a file geodatabase and a shapefile and it is not case sensitive on pointcount or shape.

Comment: I also tested with field calculator on 10.4 and you are right (not cases sensitive) but python usually is case sensitive and arcpy is less forgiving than the field calculator